# Query parameters in Script or Style tag source

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've come across a lot of websites which have parameters with the src link of the stylesheets or scripts.

Eg: Just a script i came across at Udacity.com

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/media/css/udacity/udacity.min.css?4c3a5b9f8b6eeb75ed7b7d2160c259d5">
```

Or

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/media/js/external/libs.min.js?4c3a5b9f8b6eeb75ed7b7d2160c259d5"></script>
```

What does the string after **"/udacity.min.css?"** represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cache-buster is a unique piece of code that prevents a browser from reusing an file it has already seen and cached, or saved, to a temporary memory file.

Its a part of cache-busting technique. the parameter `?4c3a5b9f8b6eeb75ed7b7d2160c259d5` indicates a query string. It will force browser to load file from server rather than cache.

Primary purpose of cache-buster is that if you modified the CSS or JS file. You would want that modified file is used rather than a cached file in the client cache.

A good [**blog**](http://www.adopsinsider.com/ad-ops-basics/what-is-a-cache-buster-and-how-does-it-work/)

Comment: Is it necessary to pass a different random string on each request?

Comment: @wdphd, No it generally done when you have modified file

Answer (score 0):

It's generally use for removing cache. For example: If you change anything in css file, some browser's will cache the old content and new changes won't propagate. To show the new changes, we tell the browser that there is something new with this file by adding a `query string`.

So when a `query string` is added the browser knows at once this is something new and hence renders the new content and therefore changes will be propagated properly and shown by browser's by default.